# React Native Flat List custom Sticky Header Indices , it has 0 index only I have to set1,2 Indices

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have to set sticky Header Indices={[1,2]} for header1, header2 text tags to be sticky how can I achieve this? thanks in advance[image]

Above is my requirement

Comment: Please don't include code as an image. Instead, paste as text and format as code using Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try using react-native [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist)